# Bean score and abstract bean

Tags: scope, abstract

I have a question related to bean scope and abstract bean.
Hard to explain but here's an example:

```
<bean id="prototypeBean" class="...X" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="singletonParentBean"  class="..Y" abtract="true"> <!--No scope so Singleton. -->
     <property name="bean" ref="prototypeBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="childPrototypeBean" class= "..z" parent="singletonParentBean" scope="prototype">
```

Is the attribute "prototypeBean" in the bean "childPrototypeBean" will have the scope "prototype" ? Because it is injected in the parent bean that is singleton.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

So response is yes. Was able to try it in my project. Every different instance of "childPrototypeBean" has a different "prototypeBean" instance.